# How do i add a delay to program before running selection query to avoid bind value being null?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I keep getting an illegal argument exception when running my app. However, this happens prior to the `Toast` messages coming up and that's why I think I need a delay.

Prior to adding on the `DatabaseHelper` class, my app was running and the proper value was coming up on both `Toast` messages, the one in the `MainActivity` and the one showing the `intent` value passed in the `DisplayResult` activity.

I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a thread sleep in a runnable.

```
        int timeYouWantToSleep = 60000;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(timeYouWantToSleep);
                        //do your work here

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

            }).start();
```

If this doesn't work, you know it's not a delay that you need.